# Cannot scroll up when layout is centered in the parent

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a scroll view containing a Linearlayout which contains some controls.
The controls has to be centered in the main view, so I wrapped the scroll view with a RelativeLayout and set the `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` which works fine.
The problem is that when I try to enter a text in the first Edittext and the tablet is in landscape mode and the keyboard appears, then the Editbox disappears and you are not able to scroll up to see the first Editbox. (I think the reason is the `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`)
How can I solve this problem to be able to scroll up and down to see all the controls when the keyboard appears.
The Layout file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"

android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/LayoutDummy" />
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/EdName" />
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/EdName" />
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/Password"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView5" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/EdPassword" />
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/Mandant"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView5" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/EdMandant" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:layout_width="359.2dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/EdLoginUrl"
        android:layout_marginTop="11.6dp" />
    <CheckBox
        android:text="Offline"
        android:id="@+id/cbOffline"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="7.9dp" />
    <TableLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Button
                android:text="Ok"
                android:id="@+id/BtnOk"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_width="100dp" />
            <Button
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:id="@+id/BtnCancel"
                android:layout_width="100dp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnSetting"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
            android:gravity="top" />
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtResult"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout></ScrollView></RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

inside your activity defined in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

try using linear layout instead of relative layout with

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```